# How I set all line in textview have same length of character?

Tags: java, android

How I set all line in textview have same length of character?

This is text in sqlite database

[image]

This is textview in android

[image]

my query code in main.class

db.open();
        Cursor c = db.getdescIntro(department,degree);

```
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {

        do {
            a  = (String)c.getString(0);                
            txt.setText(a);

            PDF = c.getString(2);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
```

My database.class

public Cursor getdescIntro(String dep,String degree)    {

return db.query("academic", new String[] {"desc","department","acapdf"},"department" + "=?" +" AND " + "degree" +"=?", new String[] {dep,degree}, null, null, null);

}

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right based on your screen shots, you're asking how to remove line breaks:

> String myNewString = myString.replaceAll("\n", "");

If you're looking for a solution to have the text fit exactly with the `TextView's` bounds, see this SO answer: [auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds)

Comment: thank you. I mean that my sentence is so long then it will down on the next line since previous space. I does not need it down to next line.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Try to remove line breaks with the code in my answer and see if it helps.